Why are the headers empty?
I am trying to get a simple redirection to work with GuzzleHttp and am using phpunit to test my code. The expected behavior is that if the requested URL ends with a "/" then the response should be a redirection to the same URL stripped with the trailing "/".
This is how my App.php looks like :
<?php
namespace Framework;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;

class App {
    public function run(ServerRequestInterface $request): ResponseInterface {
        $uri= $request->getUri()->getPath();
        if (!empty($uri) && $uri[-1] === "/") {
            $response= new Response();
            $response= $response->withStatus(301);
            $response= $response->withHeader('Location', substr($uri, 0, -1));
        }
        $response= new Response();
        $response->getBody()->write('Hello.');
        return $response;
    }
}

And I run the test in AppTest.php like this :
<?php
namespace Tests\Framework;

use Framework\App;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\ServerRequest;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class AppTest extends TestCase {
    public function testRedirectTrailingSlash() {
        $app= new App();
        $request= new ServerRequest('GET', '/some-slug/');
        $response= $app->run($request);
        $this->assertContains('/some-slug', $response->getHeader('Location'));
        $this->assertEquals('301', $response->getStatusCode());
    }
}

When I run this test, both assertions fail and it's due to the fact that the response's status code is 200 and the headers list is empty and I confirmed that by doing a var_dump().
The weirdest thing is that, I wrote this code a few months ago and it worked and as far as I remember, the only thing I did between then and now was a composer install so I don't know if it's due to a recent updates of the dependencies.
Can someone help me with this?

composer install won't update dependencies. It installs only the ones from composer.lock.

But then, what is the problem?

The issue seems to stem from the fact that you are always creating a new response object right after setting the redirection headers. This overwrites the previous response that had the redirection.
To fix this, either return the created response before closing the if statement or put the rest of the code inside an else to avoid overwriting your previous response object like the other answer. Try the below code in your App.php:
<?php
namespace Framework;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;

class App {
    public function run(ServerRequestInterface $request): ResponseInterface {
        $uri = $request->getUri()->getPath();
        if (!empty($uri) && $uri[-1] === "/") {
            $response = new Response();
            $response = $response->withStatus(301);
            $response = $response->withHeader('Location', substr($uri, 0, -1));
            return $response; 
        }

        $response = new Response();
        $response->getBody()->write('Hello.');
        return $response;
    }
}


You're right about the diagnosis I suspect, but To fix this, remove the second instance where you create a new response object... isn't actually what you've done. You haven't removed the second instance, because it's still needed for the case where the URI doesn't have the /. What you've done, correctly, is return the response inside the if, so the code doesn't  drop out of the if and overwrite the response object. I would suggest that you [edit] your post to be more accurate and clear about what you actually did :-)

Facepalm moment. Thank you very much. This is exactly the code I was supposed to write but for some reason, I forgot to return the response inside the if so even if the condition is met, the rest of the code is still executed, thank you.

You are overriding the response instance from the if statement. Do something like the following to avoid overriding the response instance:
$response = new Response();
if (!empty($uri) && $uri[-1] === "/") {
    $response = $response->withStatus(301);
    $response = $response->withHeader('Location', substr($uri, 0, -1));
} else {
    $response->getBody()->write('Hello.');
}
return $response;


Yes, thank you. I was actually supposed to return the response inside the if statement but I probably accidentally deleted the line without noticing. But this answer would work perfectly too.
